# Make headings (h1, h2, ...) inherit style from body

Tags: html, css

I want to organize pages by the importance of their text. I.e. I want to make the most important text `h1`, etc. I want to do this so that search engines will find the correct text to display in the excerpt text of results.

**However**, I don't want to have these styles dictate how the text will be shown, so I set certain defaults in the CSS for `.html` and `.body`, and would like the headings (`h1`...) to inherit from them. (And I'll tailor the styles to the pages wherever needed.)

**Unfortunately**, it seems like headings are displayed differently such as in larger font, anyway. So is there any way to tell browsers to treat headings as body text in terms of style? (I know I can set the CSS for the headings, but then what happens when someone changes the `.body` CSS, but forgets to change the `h1` CSS...)

Comment: Very wrong idea, just don't do this.

Comment: @KamilNaja Why? On some pages the heading should be one way, and on others differently. Isn't it better to tailor them to the page?

Comment: Correct me if I misunderstood you but wouldn't a solution be just to define the same class for the headers and body and change this class's css ?

Comment: @OmriAttiya That would mean writing `class="theClass"` ***everywhere***.

Comment: You can add classes using simple javascript. That way you accomplish what you want and avoiding adding `class="theClass"` everywhere

Comment: You most likely get downvoted for among others, not have made a proper research (if you would, it would give your several solutions how to make elements inherit from ancestors as well as make some unique using classes) and not provide a verifiable sample. A sample is needed so we can see what it is you have issues with, or else suggestion would be more or less wild guesses.

Comment: If you read [ask], you'll see all what I wrote is well stated what is expected of someone posting a question.

Comment: @LGSon A) Thanks for your comments. b) Inheriting from ancestors in general is not what I'm looking for. Idon't want to need to add it everywhere. As for a sample - anyone who doesn't know that headings don't inherit from body (as opposed to most other things) shouldn't be answering this question. But anyway, I do appreciate you telling me what people's reasoning is!

Comment: What you just wrote (telling what you don't want) should have been in the question. Along with a sample, showing how the markup looks like, which is highly relevant, and you would get more specific question and answers, instead of as of now, general ones like standard CSS rules and how to script something. And do note, people's reasoning is related to SO guide lines, which you failed to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set setup styles at the top of your CSS sheet like this.

```
h1{}
h2{}
body{}
```

or

```
body h1{}
body h2{}
```

To adjust these styles later on, simply add new styles further down your CSS sheet. Since your
CSS sheet is a Cascading Style Sheet it inherits styles from the top of the sheet downward.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, now you don't need to change the class everywhere because js will change it, and you accomplish having the body and headers having the same style but can still have differences:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className = "myClass";
  let h1s = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
  for (let i = 0; i < h1s.length; i++) {
    h1s[i].className = "myClass";
  }
};
```

```css
.myClass {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h1>My First Heading</h1>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The heading is still in bold, and that's something I'm afraid of, that in my browser I'll set everything, but in another browser, it will show up differently. There are 5 main~ browsers for desktop + more for mobile. But I get your point. Thanks. +1.

Comment: @ispiro I fixed it and now the heading is not bold. I hope this is the solution you looked for :D